# makedirs() gives AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'rfind'

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program that saves a backup by creating a directory for a zip file:  This is an exercise from *A byte of python*  (I'm going to give the full example so that you guys can see where he's going.)
The example code is:

```
    #! /usr/bin/env python3
    import os
    import time


    # 1. The files and directories to be backed up are specified in a list.
    source = ['~/Desktop/python']

    # 2. The backup must be stored in a main backup directory
    target_dir = '~/Dropbox/Backup/' # Remember to change this to what you'll be using

    # 3. The files are backed up into a zip file.
    # 4. the name of the zip archive is the current date and time
    target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') +'.zip'
    now = time.strftime('%H%M%S')

    # Create the subdirectory if it isn't already there.
    if not os.path.exists(today):
        os.mkdir(today) # make directory
        print('Successfully created directory', today)

    # The name of the zip file 
    target = today + os.sep + now + '.zip'

    # 5. We use the zip command to put the files in a zip archive
    zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))
    print(zip_command)
    # Run the backup
    if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
        print('Successful backup to', target)
    else:
        print('Backup FAILED')
```

This pulls up the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "backup_ver2.py", line 23, in <module>
        os.mkdir(today) # make directory
     TypeError: mkdir: illegal type for path parameter
```

My solution:

```
    import os
    import time

    today = 14052016 # I set today as a string to solve a previous issue.

    .....
    # Create the subdirectory if it isn't already there.
    if not os.path.exists(today):
        os.makedirs(today, exist_ok=True) # make directory
        print('Successfully created directory', today)
```

Which gives the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "backup_ver2a.py", line 23, in <module>
        os.makedirs(today, exist_ok=True) # make directory
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/os.py", line 222, in makedirs
        head, tail = path.split(name)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/posixpath.py", line 103, in split
         i = p.rfind(sep) + 1
    AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

This traceback has referenced lines in the module so now I know I'm in trouble.  Is it possible that the variable "today" is still at the heart of both of these errors?  Is there a better way to define today so as not to pull so many errors or is there a better way to check and create a subdirectory?  If you guys notice more errors in his example, please don't correct them.  I'm sure I'll find them soon.  :)  Thanks for any help.

Notes:  I'm running ubuntu 14.04 LTS and use python 3

Comment: `today = 14052016` this contradict with what you said "a string". String needs to be quoted

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing with @gdlmx, both errors resulting from your variable "today" which is an int and not a string and thus, you need to simple make the change to that variable from an int to a string by putting it in a quote, like the following line of code:

```
today = "14052016"
```

Once this is done the errors you're getting should be fade away.